# Iptables is not matching the chain with xtables-addons GeoIP

Tags: iptables, ubuntu-18.04, geoip

I have a strange issue with xtables-addons, in particular with xt_geoip module.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS x64 4.15.0-1051 with all the packages updated,

I installed the following packages: xtables-addons-common pkg-config xtables-addons-source libnet-cidr-lite-perl libtext-csv-xs-perl

And compiled xtables-addons-3.5 (Latest version).

The process for generating GeoIP database with xt_geoip_dl and xt_geoip_build works and I can see the module xt_geoip loaded in the kernel (lsmod) and geoip loaded in iptables (cat /proc/net/ip_tables_matches).

My iptables configuration is simple: it's meant to LOG and DROP all the connection attempts from country that are not whitelisted, into specific:

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [3607180:3023592144]
:GEOIP - [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -m geoip ! --source-country IT,IE,GB  -j GEOIP
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A GEOIP -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "GEOIP-Dropped: "
-A GEOIP -j DROP
COMMIT
```

The problem is that the chain GEOIP never get a hit, in fact the packet count is zero:

```
# iptables -L -v -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source    destination
4884K 3949M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0   0.0.0.0/0            state ESTABLISHED
30094 2417K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0   0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0   10.0.0.0/8
   41 23221 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0   172.16.0.0/12
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0   192.168.0.0/16
    0     0 GEOIP      all  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0   0.0.0.0/0            -m geoip ! --source-country IT,IE,GB

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source    destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 3609K packets, 3025M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source    destination
 517K  810M ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0   0.0.0.0/0

Chain GEOIP (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source    destination
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0   0.0.0.0/0 limit: avg 2/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4  prefix "GEOIP-Dropped: "
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0   0.0.0.0/0
```

If I try to connect from an IP in another country the connection is not dropped.

Before the latest kernel upgrade I was running version 4.15.0-1043 and the xtables-addons version compiled was 3.3 and all the GEOIP process was working smoothly.

The only strange thing is that I saw the following is in /var/log/kern.log:

```
xt_geoip: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
xt_geoip: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
```

As the kernel module is loaded, this seems to be only a warning.

Can someone please help me with this?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, a reboot of the server was required after the compile of xtables-addon.